# Laravel 8 with Sanctum Authentication (Reactjs SPA)

Tags: reactjs, laravel, single-page-application, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

I am trying to learn Laravel sanctum,
I am stuck at the **CSRF** section, after changing the cors.php config value of 'supports_credentials' into true. I'm successfully getting a 204 response when connecting **/sanctum/csrf-cookie**. But after that when trying to connect to '/login', I am getting error `419 unknown status.`

I have added this to my env file

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost:8000 // Laravel backend
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=http://127.0.0.1:3000 // React Fronend
```

Here is my **Cors.php**

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
'exposed_headers' => [],
'max_age' => 0,
'supports_credentials' => true,
```

And here's my **React Code **

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    apiClient.get("sanctum/csrf-cookie").then((response) => {
      apiClient
        .post(
          "api/login",{
            email: email,
            password: password,
          }).then((response) => {
              console.log(response);
           });
       });
  };
```

Below is apiClient's Code

```
import axios from "axios";

const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/",
  withCredentials: true
});

export default apiClient;
```

API's are working completely fine on **Postman**

Comment: You  try command.  Php artisan optimize:clear

Comment: It magically works. But how?

Comment: Laravel make cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try command. Php artisan optimize:clear

Comment: Thanks it works but can you describe the reason behind it ?

Comment: Voodoo magic! But ignorants shall say it's related to cache cleaning.